# Re-transpile JSX on the fly in a reactjs app

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Is it possible to access and modify the JSX used to create a React class and re-transpile it on the fly. For example, if you had the following:

```
var Item = React.createClass({
    render: function () { 
        return <div>Hello</div>
    }
}
```

How could we: access the raw JSX, modify it to return something else, then transpile so the changes could be seen?

YES I understand this could be extremely dangerous.

Comment: but... why? what is wrong with a `switch` then to return variable result? or get the return from an AJAX-call? Or read the results from a file...

Comment: Looks like an [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/174604).

Comment: Please edit the question to include details of what you're trying to accomplish. I'm not sure why this would be "dangerous?" Using the client side JSX transpiler isn't recommended for performance reasons.

Comment: The goal is exactly as stated: "access the raw JSX, modify it to return something else, then transpile so the changes could be seen?" That is the end goal.

Answer (score 1):

It's probably easier to compile the JSX to JS first, and then use something like esprima to make the changes you need on the AST esprima gives you. Then pretty print it to JS again.

But I have to ask what your use case is, because it doesn't seem like the very best of ideas.

Comment: Thank you. Here are the questions I want answered: How could we: access the raw JSX, modify it to return something else, then transpile so the changes could be seen?

Comment: You can use esprima-fb to get an AST representing the JS and the JSX. You would then make changes to that AST, and then pretty print it to JS with your changes.